# Force on dielectric while entering a capacitor - Connected to battery

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, dielectric

I had seen a similar question to this as below. However it considers a charged capacitor disconnected from a voltage source.

[Force on dielectric slab](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/552966)

As per my understanding from the comments, the Fringe field and energy stored due to it doesn't change outside the dielectric as its magnitude depends only on the capacitor. The only energy which varies is that inside the capacitor (part with dielectric and part without).

Now will the same proof (F= $|\frac{dU}{dx}|$ ) hold true if a battery is connected as battery might do work due to change in charge on capacitance initially and later with dielectric entering? (obviously with $\frac{1}{2}C'V^2$ being used as U where C' is equivalent Capacitance inclusive of dielectric part.